# Why I am not getting UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, uialertview

I am using parse for sign-in/sign-up process.

Everything is working fine. Until user gives wrong details.

In else part of Parse Login I have written:

```
self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
// The login failed. Check error to see why.
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error valueForKey:@"Error"]];
UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SO" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[myalert show];
```

I checked after putting breakpoints in every line.

After executing the 3rd Line i.e. `NSSString *message` the control doesn't go for alert it directly shows me UI without any alert box.

And In Log I am getting

```
[Error]: invalid login parameters (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.5)
```

I doesn't know what to do ? I have written only this code in else part.

I am using Parse Code :

```
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) 
{
    if (!error) 
    {   
        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
    } 
    else 
    {   
        NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];   // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
    }
}];
```

and In else part I want to show and alertView

Comment: Are you calling that on the main thread?

Comment: Have you implemented the delegate?

Comment: UIAlertView delegate ?

Comment: Yes; you are using `delegate:self`.

Comment: No need to add delegate for alertview, he just forgot otherButtonTitles: nil, nil in alertview method, may be this is the issue

Comment: Alert views will still show up without implementing the delegate. The delegate is for adding functionality to any controls your alert view might have.

Comment: @BKjadav No this code is working fine when I use it in other..

Comment: @trojanfoe I have updated my question

Comment: Probably you are not calling `[alert show]` on the main thread

Comment: So you are calling it from within the block?  Are **positive** that's called in the main thread?

Comment: Are you using the Xcode 7 Beta or Xcode 6.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
UIAlertView *myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SO" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
           [myalert show];
    });
```

Comment: It works...but I used the same code earlier but it work...

Comment: Waste of 11 minutes.  Closing as a dupe.

Comment: This is the correct answer for this but if you want to try other please check at   http://www.saddaweb.com/ios/why-alert-view-is-not-showing.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
NSString *errorString;
UIAlertView *AV;
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {   // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
  } else {   errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];   // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
      AV = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SO" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      [AV show];
  }
}];
```

Answer (score -1):

try to call main thread first then create the UIAlert in it

coz mostly thats happen when you are not in the main thread

hope this solve your problem goodluck